# SwiftUI List from JSON/Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, list, swiftui

Just starting out with SwiftUI so apologies for the basic question. I have a dictionary created from a JSON file of the following format:

```
{
 {
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "John.doe@domain.com"
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Jane",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "Jane.doe@domain.com"
 }
}
```

I would like to create a list of first_name that I can then use in other files, the names are unique so there shouldn't be any need for UUID. So far I can load my data into a swift file and display it with the use of:

```
struct DataTest: View {
let people = Bundle.main.decode("people.json")
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ForEach(0 ..< people.count){number in
            Text("\(people[number].first_name)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there any way that I can generate an array or list without the use of a ForEach loop? I tied something like *@State private var = people.first_name*, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Are you asking how you get a single entry from the array? Although you've left out some code, it seems that `people` is already an array.

Comment: My bad on not explaining it properly, so I want to end up with a single list with just first_name, the list in this case should be ["John", "Jane"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the is this structure:

```
struct Person {
  var first_name : String
  var last_name : String
  var email: String
}
```

and `people` is `[Person]`, you can map a single property like this:

```
let firstNamesOnly = people.map { $0.first_name }
```

or, newly in Swift 5.2:

```
let firstNamesOnly = people.map(\.first_name)
```

You could use this in a computed property and `List` by doing:

```
var firstNames : [String] {
        people.map(\.first_name)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(firstNames, id: \.self) { firstName in
                Text(firstName)
            }
        }
    }
```